# Issues with browsing local network 16.10 Ubuntu-Mate

Tags: networking, ubuntu-mate

I am unable to correctly browse my local network. What does show up I can not drill down or connect.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCCsN.jpg

I'm running 16.10, on previous version I have been able to browse my NAS. I would be asked for the login and then folders and files would be available as if they were on my PC. I would be able to browse the Windows shares. I would be able to see my network printer and router at least to the point of seeing these devices as connected to the network. I can connect to the ftp server on the NAS and I can print to my network printer. I just can see or use stuff in Caja.

Answer (score 1):

This conflict with local adresses is well-known in Linux world, and caused by the fact that `.local` domain is reserved by [Avahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29) demon and Avahi interferes with MS-like networks. 
The simplest solution could be:

1. Open Avahi configuration by address

   ```
   /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf
   ```
2. Uncomment line `#domain-name` in the [Server] section and set it to **.alocal** instead of **.local**:

   ```
   [server]
   domain-name=.alocal
   ```
3. Restart Avahi

   ```
   sudo service avahi-daemon restart
   ```
4. Flush DNS cache

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your response, all goes well until this line. 'sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart' and I get a Command not found error.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             sorry for the bad formatting but every time I hit enter to start a new line the blooming website posts what I have written.

Comment: Then you should install it first: `sudo apt install nscd`. However, flushing DNS only actual for versions before 16.04, so the steps above should work without it. Do it only if these steps fail.